# How to run `zsh-newuser-install` without modifying existing files

Tags: zsh, docker, nix

The top-level problem I want to solve is to run `zsh-newuser-install` configuration script. This is what's executed when zsh opens for the first time and sees no `.zprofile`/`.zshrc`/... files. I don't want it to mess with my current configuration, so I'd like to run it in some isolated environment, just to see what are its options and to inspect the configuration it generates for me.

My idea was to run zsh inside docker container. Because I'm not fluent with docker, but I'm somewhat with nix - I used the nix package manager to build the container with such an expression:

```
docker-example =
  pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
    name = "with-zsh";
    config = {
      Cmd = [ "${pkgs.zsh}/bin/zsh" ];
    };
    copyToRoot = with pkgs; [
      coreutils
      zsh
    ];
  }
```

After loading the container into docker I run it with:

```
docker run -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr -i -t with-zsh:b9049wbw7bbil80pnnvl4cgxb2s9kr15
```

and it drops me into a `zsh` shell at `/` in a bare-bones system with no homedir and no zsh config files present anywhere. It doesn't run me through the `zsh-newuser-install` configurator. I also found the init script at "/share/zsh/5.9/scripts/newuser" and sourcing it has seemingly no action. I would expect to jump into a cli configurator.

I suspect that problem might be with lack of users? Running `whoami` yields:

```
#whoami
> whoami: cannot find name for user ID 0: No such file or directory
```

I'd appreciate help with solving this particular problem or explanation on why it works unexpectedly to me, but also all the other ideas of how to check out some zsh configurations without messing with my current one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need Docker for this. Just start your shell with an empty home dir other than your own:

```bash
HOME=$( mktemp -d ) exec zsh
```